# Get last character from id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I need to get the last character of the id of an element and use it in order to find another element by id in the same page.

What I've tried so far:

```
$(".spoilerButton").each(function(){
        $currentId=($this).attr("id").slice(-1);
        $hiddenContent=$("#spoiler"+$currentId);
        $this.click(function(){
                $hiddenContent.toggle(500);
        });
});
```

Basically, every element of class spoilerButton with an id of spoilerButtonN where N an integer, has a corresponding element with id spoilerN that needs to show/hide, once it is clicked.

The code does not seem to run the `$currentId=($this).attr("id").slice(-1);` part, where I try to get the last character (N) from the spoilerButton's id.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: You don't seem to define $this. And it would be simpler to do ̀`this.id.slice(-1)`

Comment: I don't think it's generally a recommended practice to prefix all your variable names with `$`.

Comment: Right. If there's any convention, it's that `$var` should be a variable containing a jQuery object, e.g. `$this = $(this)`.

Comment: You should also declare local variables with `var`. You're setting  global variables `$currentId` and `$hiddenContent`, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have your parens in the wrong place:

```
$currentId=$(this).attr("id").slice(-1);
// Note     ^    ^
```

---

Or of course, specifically with respect to the `id` attribute, `$(this).attr("id")` is just a long way to write `this.id`, so:

```
$currentId=this.id.slice(-1);
```

...but that's not true for *all* attributes, just certain reflected ones like `id`.